# How to make the grey hints that point the type on methods auto appear?

Tags: visual-studio, syntax-highlighting

I am watching video lesson and when teacher starts writing code, grey formatting  letters appear.  I attached a screenshot to this question.

Do anybody know how to activate it? I am using Visual Studio 2022 and mine doesn't have it.

[image]

Comment: Is that the Resharper extension perhaps?

Comment: [Inline Hints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-text-editor-csharp-advanced?view=vs-2019#inline-hints) (starting [from](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2019-v16-8-preview-2/#net-productivity) VS 2019 16.8).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to Tools -> Options and search for the following options. Check the boxes and you're good to go.

[image]

Comment: Turn that on with multiple solutions of 50+ projects open if it's [time for a break](https://xkcd.com/303/) :D